# how to bind multiple related parameters in one route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have Two related Models Anime, Episode

and I have changed the RouteKeyName for both of them

In Anime Model :

```
public function getRouteKeyName() 
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

In Episode Model :

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'ep_num'; // episode number
}
```

to view an Episode, I use this :

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('play/{anime}/{episode}', 'EpisodeController@index');
```

**EpisodeController.php**

```
public function index(Anime $anime, Episode $episode)
{
    return view('play')->with([
        'anime' => $anime,
        'episode' => $episode
    ]);
}
```

for example if i have this link

.../play/naruto/10

then by using route model binding i will have the first episode with ep_num=10

Instead I want to have the episode with ep_num=10 when

```
anime_id = $anime->id
```

is there any way to do this inside RouteServiceProvider

i want to apply this for all the routes containing both anime and episode such as :

```
Route::delete('anime/{anime}/episode/{episode}/delete', 'EpisodeController@destroy');
Route::get('anime/{anime}/episode/{episode}/edit', 'EpisodeController@edit');
Route::put('anime/{anime}/episode/{episode}/edit', 'EpisodeController@update');
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're after. What do you mean by `anime_id = $anime->id`?

Comment: anime_id is a foreign key in episodes table and i want it to be equal to the id of the anime in the route

Comment: Ok, and is the relationship in your `Episode` model for anime just called `anime`?

Comment: yes, it is called anime

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
Route::bind('episode', function ($slug) {

    $episode = Episode::where('slug', $slug);

    if (request()->route()->hasParameter('anime')) {
        $episode->whereHas('anime', function ($q) {
            $q->where('slug', request()->route('anime'));
        });
    }

    return $episode->firstOrFail();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That helped me a lot , Thanks